# Is this possible to make 3d scene in cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I made mobile game in cocos2d-x ( just simple test to learn engine ) and I have 12 scenes, all are in 2d graphics. I want just one to change to be 3d, simple shooting on 3d models and 3d walls.
Is this possible to make and how in cocos2d-x despite name suggests it is only 2d ?

( I looked on youtube is demo to import 3d models but I need to shoot inside house with real walls and stuffs which is kinda different).

Comment: It's possible alright, but you have to do all rendering via OpenGL by subclassing a CCNode and adding your OpenGL (3D) rendering code in its draw (or visit?) method, setting GL states and what not and restoring the cocos2d default GL states afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's absolutely possible.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sHC8xHPtO50
- https://github.com/chukong/FantasyWarrior3D
- http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Fantasy_Warrior_3D

If you want to implement 3D scene by yourself, it's also possible. You might need to create a class which is derived from cocos2d::Node. And then implement the draw method.

```
void YourClass::draw(cocos2d::Renderer *renderer,
    const cocos2d::Mat4 &transform, uint32_t flags) override
{
    m_customCommand.init(globalZOrder);
    m_customCommand.func = CC_CALLBACK_0(
        YourClass::onRender, this, transform, flags);
    renderer->addCommand(&m_customCommand);
}
```

the draw method is only for submitting rendering commands that are supposed to be invoked from actual rendering timing.

```
void YourClass::onRender(const cocos2d::Mat4 &transform, uint32_t flags)
{
    // render whatever you want using OpenGL ES 2.0 APIs
}
```

But you should aware the following.

CCNode.h:

```
 * The following GL states will be enabled by default:
 * - `glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);`
 * - `glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);`
 * - `glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);`
 * - `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);`
 * AND YOU SHOULD NOT DISABLE THEM AFTER DRAWING YOUR NODE
 * But if you enable any other GL state, you should disable it after drawing your node.
```

Answer (score 0):

The official docs document 3D at: http://cocos2d-x.org/docs/programmers-guide/3d/index.html 3D was added in version 3.

The tests obtained from building from source contain several 3D examples:

```
cocos2d-x/build/bin/cpp-tests/cpp-tests
```

This is the first one:

[image]

and the source is present at: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/7350aeca8cf2c5bea3c3484d50202bf13cc18041/tests/cpp-tests/Classes/Scene3DTest/Scene3DTest.cpp